# django filter by fields that can change

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this model :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#FFFF00')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    decision = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

For example, if I want to filter all the projects named 'hello_project' with a price of 10, I can do this :

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(Q(name='hello_project') & Q(price=10))
```

What I want to do is filter by lists that can change :

```
fields = ["name", "price"]
filters = ["hello_project", 10]
```

Is there a way to do something like this that works ? (lists size can change) :

```
projects = Project.objects.filter(Q({fields[0]}={filters[0]}) & Q({fields[1]}={filters[1]})
```

I've done this:

```
def get_state(project):
    return replace(project.state)


def get_name(project):
    return project.name


def get_price(project):
    return str(project.price) + "K€"


def get_decision(project):
    return project.decision


functions = {
    'state': get_state,
    'name': get_name,
    'price': get_price,
    'decision': get_decision
}


def filter_projects(fields, filters):
    all_projects = Project.objects.all()
    filtered_projects = []

    for i in range(len(fields)):
        for project in all_projects:
            if str(functions[fields[i]](project)) == str(filters[i]):
                filtered_projects.append(project)
        all_projects = filtered_projects
        filtered_projects = []
    return all_projects
```

It works but it's very long with a lot of projects so I want to know if I can do this in one line

Comment: I think there is some typo in this `if str(functions[fields[i]](project)) == str(filters[i])):` kindly check it.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I edited my post, and added my 'functions' switch statement (which is very badly named, I admit) and removed the extra parenthesis (which was here because it's not exactly what I do in my code but it's easier to understand like this)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a dictionary.

```
filter_kwargs = {
    "name": "hello_project",
    "price": 10,
}
projects = Project.objects.filter(**filter_kwargs)
```